# Обособленный оборот или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Цитата из нобелевской лекции И. Бродского:

> Именно  в  этом, скорее прикладном,  чем  платоническом  смысле
> следует понимать замечание Достоевского, что "красота спасет мир"...

Почему нет запятой перед *"смысле"*? Я так понимаю, *"скорее прикладном, чем платоническом"* — обособленный оборот, что доказывается отсутствием запятой после вводного слова *"скорее"*, которое стоит в начале оборота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Именно в **этом, скорее прикладном, чем платоническом смысле** следует понимать замечание Достоевского, что "красота спасет мир"...*

**Примечание.** Сочетание "скорее прикладном, чем платоническом" рассматривается как определительный оборот.

Если Бродский так написал, то значит так оно и есть. Это авторский выбор. Правила Розенталя допускают **любой тип отношений**, если первое прилагательное является местоименным (указательным, притяжательным или определительным).

Например: **Эти недавно опубликованные** стихи были написаны много времени назад. Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего **этого**, **так нашумевшего,** дерзновения. **Другой, не менее важный** раздел соглашения посвящен вопросам культурного сотрудничества.

У Розенталя такие определения однородного вида называются **пояснительными**, они рассмотрены в разделе "Однородные и неоднородные определения" http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Я так понимаю эту тему. По смыслу они имеют уточняющее или пояснительное значение, но  разделяются запятой, как однородные определения (интонация **перечислительная**).
Но почему мы отказываемся от обособления и используем перечислительную интонацию? При перечислении определения представлены как **равноправные, независимые**, а при обособлении второе определение выделено (нам приходится подчеркивать его голосом), а это требуется далеко не всегда.

В данном случае автора больше устраивали именно однородные отношения.

Comment: *Если Бродский так написал, то значит так оно и есть*. -- Я не знаю, публикуется ли эта лекция с рукописи Бродского или с кем-то сделанной аудиозаписи, конспекта, т. п.

Comment: Мне кажется, что предложение без обособления читается более естественно.  А вот местоимение "этом" автору хотелось подчеркнуть, поэтом у там стоит запятая.

Comment: Кстати, мне тут намедни ещё попалась ситуация с отсутствием запятой. Не хочу отдельный вопрос создавать, поэтому спрошу у вас тут. Это из Емца: *"Я оплакивал все те вещи, которые родители были не в состоянии купить. Девушек, которые доставались другим и многое иное, по внутреннему списку"*. Почему тут запятой нет перед "и"? Корректорский косяк?

Comment: Да, запятая пропущена. Нет причин, чтобы не закрывать определительное придаточное запятой. А у меня к вам вопрос: почему из Емца, а не из Емеца? Мне кажется, так некрасиво. Это выбор носителя фамилии?  Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Возможно склонение мужской фамилии с выпадением гласного (Еленца, Еленцу) и без выпадения гласного (Еленеца, Еленецу). Второй вариант предпочтителен (ведь фамилии выполняют и юридическую функцию), но окончательное решение – за носителем фамилии.

Comment: Это авторский выбор: везде он сам так склоняет свою фамилию. Вот, к примеру, скриншот с названием его подкаста, подкаст выложен на личной страничке писателя в ВК (то есть не какой-то модератор так писал название, а сам Емец): https://i.imgur.com/HxqV1xh.png

Comment: Спасибо!  А я уже привыкла говорить "Емеца"... Ведь в начальной форме совпадают варианты: Емц и Емец.  Интересно, как другие говорят?  (Александр Стрелец, как вы говорите? :)) Придется переучиваться.  Кстати, вам нравится его новая серия "Ева и магические существа"? Он собирается писать третью книгу, вроде бы обещал?

Comment: Я пока не читал, мне как-то трудно въехать. Вышло так, что я взрослел -- и взрослели основные серии Емца: Гроттер-Буслаев-ШНЫР. И возвращаться в детский стиль, ну... Не под настроение, по крайней мере пока. Я и прочие детские книги его не читал. Вот "Университетские истории" -- это да!

Comment: А я эти истории не читала, сейчас посмотрела одну страничку: смешные! Мне такие очень нравятся. Гроттер я не люблю и мало что читала, из Шныров пыталась прочесть одну книгу – такая муть (ну на первый взгляд).  А "Буслаева" очень люблю, и "Ева" мне нравится. Там коктейль из магии и философии, вот что мне по душе. За сюжетом я не особо слежу, а  картинки-эпизоды – просто мр-р-р! Я вообще книги воспринимаю как  отдельные живые картины где-нибудь в музее.  Они эмоционально воспринимаются и лучше запоминаются. Как вам такой подход к литературе? А вы умеете рисовать такие картины?

Comment: Оригинальный подход) Нет, рисовать я не умею, мне лень учиться. К тому же дорого нынче рисовать, для текста нужен только ноутбук и текстовый редактор, а для рисования масса расходников, от холста до красок. Выбирайте, родители, детям то хобби, которое подешевле))

Comment: Я же в переносном смысле.... Словесная живопись в литературе, и все такое. Так что никаких расходников, кроме ноутбука.  Вот у Маяковского интересный цветовой образ: окнам раздали горящие желтые карты. Я представляю, что это пожар. Страшно так! А это всего лишь свет зажгли вечером.  Но это уже крайности.  Кажется,  нашему поэту не помешала бы консультация у психолога.

Comment: Я никак не говорю  Мою фамилию тоже иногда склоняют так: Стрелеца. До Емца пока не добрался (чё-то некада пока), но он в списке на почитать. Меня несколько лет назад увлёк Сергей Лукьяненко, ну и Гарри Поттер (читал 3 раза , теперь хочу на английском). Сейчас пытаюсь Бесов прочитать, ну не идёт и всё, на 10-й стр. завис...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Лукьяненко сопровождает меня по жизни уже лет двадцать, его влияние на меня гораздо более сильное, чем Емца)

Comment: @Sharon иногда авторы заигрываются с образами и выдают что-то не совсем вразумительное, или двоящееся, или невнятное. Образ Маяковского, как по мне, из последних. Окно можно сравнить с горящей жёлтой картой, но при чём тут 'раздали'?

Comment: Книгами Лукьяненко я когда-то очень увлекалась, а потом разлюбила. Сейчас ничего не хочется перечитать, ну просто ни странички.  Его и рядом с Емецом не поставишь – по части глубины и разнообразия философии, эмоциональности, фантазийности, яркости. И еще какой-то театральности – в лучшем смысле этого слова. А в Хогвартсе я вообще учусь, по субботам. Тут недавно зелье варили из семян гвоздики, уж очень она на червячков похожа (обратите внимание).

Comment: Александр, не читайте Поттера на английском языке. Я тут не так давно затеяла такой же эксперимент, который закончился на первой же странице. Таким бесцветным, скучным и невыразительным показался мне английский язык по сравнению с русским (а ведь это оригинал!). Сразу вспомнила его неаристократическое происхождение: французский в его нормандской диалектной форме + местное разговорное наречие англосаксов.  Интересно, это правда (я у одного французского историка прочитала). И всё рано его (английский язык) люблю – сердцу не прикажешь.